# How does one implement the Google Maps 3D API (or similar) for Flex with a local map cache?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, gis

I am writing a Flex application for use on a private intranet with no external Internet access. I want to use Google's 3D Maps Flex API, but it must be connected to the internet to download map tiles on demand.

Is there a way to locally cache the 3D map tiles and data so that I can run this app without an internet connection? And if not, is there a 3D GIS that supports Flex integration and allows for a local map cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the maps on non public facing sites is against the rules of all the map providers under their free licence other than Yahoo and openstreetmap.org. Also I think there are some limits to tile caching enforced for several of the providers, mostly which prohibit such activity. openstreetmap.org allows you to cache tiles.

Comment: Please post your source that states Microsoft does not allow Bing Maps to be used on non public facing sites.